# MySQL Master(Active) - Master(Active) Replication

Tags: mysql, database, session, database-replication, master-slave

I am intending to use Master-Master (Active-Active) architecture of MySQL in my project.
In my project I have two sites active and disaster site. On the active site, we do use 2 MySQL DB server - one is Master Active other is Master Passive which replicates data to Disaster site. Master Active also replicates to Master passive. All the three app servers write only on master active.

Now, I am planning to use Master Passive as Master active. Now, active site will have two master active and one app server will write on one master active and other two app servers will write on 2nd master active.

It would be great if you can enlighten the pros and cons of using this archirtecture. What issues may arise and what are the remedies for them ?

FYI.. Session stickiness is also used from web servers to app servers.

Thanks,

Prashant Gupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? Improved availability? Performance?

How do you plan to manage the connections from the app servers to the database instances? Floating IP addresses? Static mappings? What about failover? What monitoring do you have in place to measure availability of master nodes? Replication lag?

Comment: We want to distribute the write loads between two db servers.As I have already mentioned that We will use static mapping from app server to db server. If one app server fails, web server will never redirect the requests to failed application server. If db server fails, then this will need manual intervention. We do already have scripts in place which periodically checks the availability of master node. For Replication latency check we use heartbeat.Replication lag is 0

Comment: `web server will never redirect the requests to failed application server` - how does that work? `We want to distribute the write loads between two db servers` - then master-master async replication isn't going to help - your write load will be higher.